# Resizing the Tumblr Like button?

Tags: button, resize, tumblr

I am using a Tumblr like button provided by ThinkingStiff on like-button.tumblr.com and am having some problems.

I don't know if this is the right place to ask this question, but I couldn't contact ThinkingStiff through his like-button tumblr so this seemed like my best shot. First of all, I'd like to thank him for his codes on how to add a Like and Reblog button to any theme. I am using them on my blog over at shelteryou.tumblr.com and they are working wonderfully. However, as you can probably tell, the like button is a bit too big for my theme. I was wondering if there was a way to shrink it down to a more suitable size? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

They use a background-image, so if you want to have a different size, you'd have to change the image resolution (or create a new image) in your favorite image editor. Then upload it to Tumblr (they provide a [upload service for theme files](http://www.tumblr.com/themes/upload_static_file) only) or make a `data` URI out of it.

Then change the URL in `background-image: url(…)` to the new one (the first for the grey image, the second for the red one).

If you need the current images (so you can save them), copy/paste the two `data` URIs (everything inside the brackets) to your browser address bar.

Comment: @Nikita: If this answer solved your question/problem, you can mark it as accepted by clicking at the checkmark.